# How to deal with the different type of np.array(list) in py2 and py3 when using pyhdf?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, typeerror, pyhdf

I want to save something as variable in hdf by pyhdf.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from pyhdf.SD import *

var = 'PRESSURE_INDEPENDENT_SOURCE'
vartype = 4

hdf4 =  SD('./a.hdf', 2 | 4)

dset = hdf4.create(var, vartype, (1,13))
a = 'AFGL_1976'
b = np.array([list(a.ljust(13))])
dset[:] = b
```

It works in py2 and `b.type` is `|S1`.

But, `b.dtype` is `<U1` in py3 and I got this error when running the last row of my code:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('<U1') to dtype('S1') according to the rule 'safe'
```

If I add `b = b.astype('S1')` in py3, there's the same error. But, `b.dtype` is `|S1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
b = np.array(list(a.ljust(13)),dtype='S1')
```